# Piranha CMS disable image resizing

Tags: image, resize

I'm currently building a website with Piranha CMS MVC.
I noticed when I upload an image, the quality gets significantly worse.

I use this to load the image on to my page:

```
<img class="fullwidthimg" src="@UI.Content(Model.Regions.image.Id)" alt="@Model.Regions.image.Name" />
```

I'm familiar with HTML/CSS/JS but .NET is still quite new to me.

I was unable to find a solution in the forum or on the Piranha website.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, until i went poking around in the source. I found in the Content class there is a method called SetFileMeta that is used to resize the image.

What I found was a system setting being used as the max width. You can find the setting under `System -> Parameters -> IMAGE_MAX_WIDTH`. Increasing this number will increase the max width of the image, however, if you set the value to zero, the image will not be resized when it is uploaded.